# Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 not working properly on 19.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 19.04, intel, iwlwifi

Bare with me folks I'm an ubuntu newb...

Running an HP ENVY laptop with Ubuntu 19.10 and the wifi keeps dropping signal and constantly needs a prod to liven it up.  After a bit of a fight with an errant display driver I updated ubuntu from 18.04 where the intel wifi beastie was working fine.

[ubuntu about info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHwcY.png)

I note that the software updates page states that it isn't working (which it might as well not be).  It runs for a while and stops. If you prod the wifi on the network settings it sometimes livens it up before things timeout.

[software updates page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb92u.png)

I checked with Intel and it looks like kernel 4.1 & 4.2 are supported and 19.04 is 5.0 (I believe)

[Intel page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XS4e.png)

How is this ubuntu newb going to fix this?

Many thanks
Steve

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide contains some clues, esp. useful is the *Device and Recognition and Operation* section in Troubleshooting, as it provides clues needed to find information online, here, or to provide details we need to help you.

Comment: Thanks @guiverc I'm comfortable that the device is still working, I think it's a driver issue after upgrading. It was working reasonably well before but it seems to me that the kernel update doesn't have the correct driver for that device.  I upgraded as the updater said the version of ubuntu was no longer supported (or words similar), I updated a couple of times until I didn't get that message but it looks like I've got a kyboshed driver now.